# AWS Rouet 53 Private Hosted Zone route traffic to Ec2 hosted on Private Subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I have below question:
I want to host Web Server but want to make sure external (user accessing the web server over internet) DNS resolution should go via organization Data Center. Data Center is connected to AWS region via Direct Connect.

Is my below proposed plan correct ?

I am planning to use Route 53 Private Hosted Zone. Private Hosted Zone will have record set for Internal Classic Load Balancer. The internal Classic Load Balancer will point to Web Server Hosted in Private Subnet.

Answer (score 0):

If your AWS is already connected with organization Data Center using Direct connect they can access your servers Privately so no action requires here.

Second If you want to Host Website Publically over the Internet, You just need to provide the ELB endpoint to the DNS Manager (Person who is managing DNS Server) and he will make a cname entry as

> ELB Endpoint --> your site name.

Comment: Can we use internal Classic Load Balancer which will point to Web Server Hosted in Private Subnet to route the user request from internet ?